# adjusting html code for make restriction search box

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress

I have created searchbox which include questions and answers. questions is written and answer between bracktes. like Quesiton1 - ((Answer1))

user has to write the question and press enter to view the answers
each user will have 10 attempts to view 10 questions and answers.

but my problem some users write the wrong question and when they press enter they got NO ANSWER and it count 1 of 10 attempts which is unfair

so what I need is to modify the code, where the users can search for the question. and click on the question to view the answer (and he has 10 attempts also)
that means users can make sure the question is available before press enter or click to view the question

here is my code

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
* {

  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#myInput {
  background-image: url('/css/searchicon.png');
  background-position: 10px 12px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}

#myUL {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#myUL li a {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-top: -1px; /* Prevent double borders */
  background-color: #0a2351;
  padding: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: white;
  display: block
}

#myUL li a:hover:not(.header) {
  background-color: #eee;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>DrNapester - TestBank System</h2>

<input type="text" id="myInput" placeholder="Write the question here :)" title="Type in a name">
<ul id="myUL" style="display: none;">
  <li style="display: none;"><a href="Napester.html#">Question1 - (((Answer1)))</a></li>
  <li style="display: none;"><a href="Napester.html#">Question2 - (((Answer2)))</a></li>
  <li style="display: none;"><a href="Napester.html#">Question3 - (((Answer3)))</a></li>
  <li style="display: none;"><a href="Napester.html#">Question4 - (((Answer4)))</a></li>
  <li style="display: none;"><a href="Napester.html#">Question5 - (((Answer5)))</a></li>


<script>
// Number of guesses the user has made
var guesses = 0

// Get the input field
var input = document.getElementById("myInput");

// Execute a function when the user presses a key on the keyboard
input.addEventListener("keypress", function(event) {
  // If the user presses the "Enter" key on the keyboard
  if (event.key === "Enter") {
    // Cancel the default action, if needed
    event.preventDefault();

    myFunction()
  }
}); 


var UL = document.getElementById("myUL");
// hilde the list by default
UL.style.display = "none";

var searchBox = document.getElementById("myInput");

// show the list when the input receive focus
searchBox.addEventListener("focus",  function(){
    // UL.style.display = "block";
});

// hide the list when the input receive focus
searchBox.addEventListener("blur", function(){
    UL.style.display = "none";
});


function myFunction() {
    guesses += 1
    if (guesses >= 10) {
        window.alert("You have finished your 10 attempts.");
        return
    }

    var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
    input = document.getElementById("myInput");
    ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    // if the input is empty hide the list
    if(filter.trim().length < 1) {
        ul.style.display = "none";
        return false;
    } else {
        ul.style.display = "block";
    }

    li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
    for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
        a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];

        // This is when you want to find words that contain the search string
     if (a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) { 
        li[i].style.display = "";
     } else {
        li[i].style.display = "none";
    } 

    // This is when you want to find words that start the search string
    /*if (a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().startsWith(filter)) {
        li[i].style.display = "";
    } else {
        li[i].style.display = "none";
    }*/
    }
}
</script>


</body></html>
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so here's the answer to your problems, what was needed was to create a variable that would track the number of results. If it's above 0 then we add to the guesses. See the code below for reference

```js
function myFunction() {
    // Remove the line below
    // guesses += 1
    if (guesses >= 10) {
        window.alert("You have finished your 10 attempts.");
        return
    }

    var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
    input = document.getElementById("myInput");
    ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    // if the input is empty hide the list
    if(filter.trim().length < 1) {
        ul.style.display = "none";
        return false;
    } else {
        // Place it here
        guesses += 1;
        ul.style.display = "block";
    }

    li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
    for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
        a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];

        // This is when you want to find words that contain the search string
     if (a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) { 
        li[i].style.display = "";
     } else {
        li[i].style.display = "none";
    } 

    // This is when you want to find words that start the search string
    /*if (a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().startsWith(filter)) {
        li[i].style.display = "";
    } else {
        li[i].style.display = "none";
    }*/
    }
}
```

```js
// Number of guesses the user has made
var guesses = 0

// Get the input field
var input = document.getElementById("myInput");

// Execute a function when the user presses a key on the keyboard
input.addEventListener("keypress", function(event) {
  // If the user presses the "Enter" key on the keyboard
  if (event.key === "Enter") {
    // Cancel the default action, if needed
    event.preventDefault();

    myFunction()
  }
}); 

var attemptsDiv = document.getElementById("attempts");
var UL = document.getElementById("myUL");
// hilde the list by default
UL.style.display = "none";

var searchBox = document.getElementById("myInput");

// show the list when the input receive focus
searchBox.addEventListener("focus",  function(){
    // UL.style.display = "block";
});

// hide the list when the input receive focus
searchBox.addEventListener("blur", function(){
    UL.style.display = "none";
});


function myFunction() {
    var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
    input = document.getElementById("myInput");
    ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    var trimmedFilter = filter.trim();
    // if the input is empty hide the list
    if(trimmedFilter.length < 1) {
        ul.style.display = "none";
        return false;
    } else {
        ul.style.display = "block";
    }

    li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
    
    var resultCount = 0;
    
    for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
        a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];

        // This is when you want to find words that contain the search string
     if (a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) { 
        li[i].style.display = "";
        resultCount++;
     } else {
        li[i].style.display = "none";
    } 

    // This is when you want to find words that start the search string
    /*if (a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().startsWith(filter)) {
        li[i].style.display = "";
    } else {
        li[i].style.display = "none";
    }*/
    }
    
    if (resultCount) {
        guesses += 1;
        
        attemptsDiv.innerHTML = guesses;
        if (guesses >= 10) {
            window.alert("You have finished your 10 attempts.");
            return
        }
    }
}
```

```css
* {

  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#myInput {
  background-image: url('/css/searchicon.png');
  background-position: 10px 12px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}

#myUL {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#myUL li a {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-top: -1px; /* Prevent double borders */
  background-color: #0a2351;
  padding: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: white;
  display: block
}

#myUL li a:hover:not(.header) {
  background-color: #eee;
}
```

```html
<h2>DrNapester - TestBank System</h2>

<input type="text" id="myInput" placeholder="Write the question here :)" title="Type in a name">
<ul id="myUL" style="display: none;">
  <li style="display: none;"><a href="Napester.html#">Question1 - (((Answer1)))</a></li>
  <li style="display: none;"><a href="Napester.html#">Question2 - (((Answer2)))</a></li>
  <li style="display: none;"><a href="Napester.html#">Question3 - (((Answer3)))</a></li>
  <li style="display: none;"><a href="Napester.html#">Question4 - (((Answer4)))</a></li>
  <li style="display: none;"><a href="Napester.html#">Question5 - (((Answer5)))</a></li>
</ul>
<div>Attempts: <span id="attempts">0</span></div>
```

Comment: I tried to do so , but it doesn't work ...

Comment: @Dr.JaberALShemmari mmm, this might be because of the `if (guess >= 10)` being at the top. Try moving that after the `if...else` statement with the `guess += 1` code. Share if it works, then I'll update code

Comment: the same code which i posted ,, if you can modify it please ,, or at least show the number of attempts left

Comment: @Dr.JaberALShemmari Attempts left lololol, this isn't a freelance site. We attempt till we can't attempt no more.

Comment: @Dr.JaberALShemmari I've updated the code. This should work

Comment: Thanks aloooooot you are the best :) because I'm new for coding ... that last question plzzzz if you can help me ,, can I show the number of attempts in body , below the search box?? plzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz

Comment: @Dr.JaberALShemmari Done, good luck with your coding adventure man, and please, if this is the answer, then just mark it as so.

Comment: thanks alot , but the attempts is not working ,, when I search for question it still attempts:0

Comment: Did you refresh the page?

Comment: @Dr.JaberALShemmari You might need to refresh the page

Comment: thanks alot , by the way I tried the code but the problem if person reach the 10 questions he can search more than 10 questions

Comment: @Dr.JaberALShemmari yes, this should be your next step. Isn't this the next part of the assignment/project you are working on?